# How to access a displayobject on stage in a class that is not a document class

Tags: actionscript-3

How to access a display object on the stage in a class which is not a document class?

**I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve passing the stage as a parameter to the class.**

One solution i always come across is using "[TopLevel.as](http://www.senocular.com/flash/actionscript/?file=ActionScript_3.0/TopLevel.as)". Is it a good method because as far as I have heard using [global variables is not recommended](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad) because it might cause some problems while working on big projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All display objects have a addedToStage event dispatched when they are added to the display list, which gives you a reference to the stage. So you could do something like this:

```
// In the constructor
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);

// A class level function
private function onAdded(e:Event):void {
    // get reference from stage, eg:
    // stage.getChildByName("nameHere");
}
```

There is no need to use the "Top Level" class, which is relying on global (ie: static) properties.

Comment: I am sorry i don't understand the method can you suggest any tutorial or an example using this method?

Comment: TopLevel.as has an example of it.

Comment: you mean to say we can use the TopLevel.as extend the document class with it and use the static stage variable of TopLevel to access the display objects in the sub classes...